# MySQL: Calculation based on SUM in update query

Tags: mysql, sql

My SQL table looks like this, it has about 500 records and the volume_percentage is currently empty:

```
id  | volume | volume_percentage
--------------------------------
1   | 3151   | 0.00
2   | 832    | 0.00
3   | 39011  | 0.00
[..]
499 | 2311   | 0.00
500 | 1201   | 0.00
```

I want to populate the volume_percentage field of each record. The volume percentage should reflect the % of volume this record has compared to the total.

So basically:

```
volume_percentage = volume / SUM(volume) * 100;
```

Using PHP and a while loop of 500 queries makes this easily possible, but that doesn't sound really optimal to me (this is a process that needs to be done on a regular basis, as the volumes often change). Is there a way to do this in pure SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `join` and aggregation:

```
update mytable t cross join
       (select sum(volume) as sumvolume
        from mytable
       ) s
    set volume_percentage = 100 * volume / s.sumvolume;
```